# Identify this bug

Tags: species-identification, entomology, diptera

So we found this bug and it wasn't in our software for a change. Any help identifying it is appreciated. The bug was found in Cambridge, Massachusetts.

Three of the pictures are over 2MB, (and 2 of them are useful, I think), so I can't post them here, but I can give a link to the album: https://photos.app.goo.gl/DK7NBqZtfCaXi8BS8

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll try to fix the links.

Comment: Well, it's a fly. Possibly a Robber fly (Asilidae) or Thick-headed fly (Conopidae)

Comment: How do you know it's a fly?

Comment: Agreeing with @RHA that you have a fly here (the fourth photo shows a haltere [AKA balancer] just above the hind leg/just below the wing, which is what Diptera have instead of hind wings); I believe that it's a Soldier Fly (Family Stratiomyidae), but would like other photos (if possible) before comitting myself to that level of precision.

Comment: @theresawalrus bugs should have their front wings hardened to wing-cases callers elytra. They are covering the remaining hind wings. Your specimen doesn't show that.

Comment: @ArthurJFrost there are more pictures on the google drive album if you need more.

Comment: @theresawalrus ... sorry about the tardy reply: one of the album photos was a great almost: the one with the specimen against a solid background might have helped if it hadn't lost resolution when zooming in.  If you still have the specimen and can get an in-focus extreme closeup of one wing, that would help immensely in confirming or denying my guess.

Comment: @ArthurJFrost Sorry, we put it out of its misery because it couldn't fly well anymore. It would try, but could no longer generate enough lift so would just glide down.